# Not able to create a second table in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem with my SQLite database in Android, I create my first table here User Create a List name ex: Vegetables and it will display in Recycler View it was created successfully and is displayed.

When I create a second table where user can input names of vegetables like carrot, beans and it wants to save inside the vegetables :

[image]

When I insert values for the second table it shows "Added Successfully!" but the table was not created and it doesn't insert any values.

DatabaseHelper:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Database Name
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "names.db";

    // Table 1
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "listview_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "ITEM_NAME";
    private static final String COLUMN_IMAGE = "image_bitmap";

    // Table 2
    private static final String TABLE2_NAME = "listitem_name";
    public static final String COLUMN1_ID = "ID";
    public static final String COLUMN2_TITLE = "LISTITEMS_NAME";

 @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        String query =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                        + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  ,"
                        + COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT, "
                        + COLUMN_IMAGE + " BLOB )";

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);

        String query1 =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE2_NAME + "("
                        + COLUMN1_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"
                        + COLUMN2_TITLE + "  TEXT )";

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query1);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE2_NAME);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }
```

Creating my first table inside DatabaseHelper it was successful (here only I create a name Vegetable and display that in Listview):

```
void createlist(String title, byte[] image) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_TITLE, title);
        cv.put(COLUMN_IMAGE, image);
        Long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        if (result == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Added Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Creating my second table inside DatabaseHelper it was not successful (here only I create a names of vegetable (carrot,beans) and display that inside the  Listview):

```
 void itemlist(String items) {
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

            cv.put(COLUMN2_TITLE, items);

            Long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE2_NAME, null, cv);
            if (result == -1) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Added Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

Activity.java:

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
     

                String name = lname.getText().toString();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(lname.getText().toString())) {
                    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                    db.itemlist(name);
                    Toast.makeText(AddItems.this, "Added Sucessfully !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else
                    Toast.makeText(AddItems.this, "The name cannot be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

increase database version every time when you change table or any column into table

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 4);
        this.context = context;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase database version every time when you change table or any column into table.